# Solar System program

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to make a program with solar system planets.I have the Sun and planets (Mercury, Venus, Earth .. ) and i want to make the planets to move around the sun.

[Here is the math part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjEuI.png)

Where 
 **X=R1 * cos α 
 Y=R2 * sin α 
 α = 1**

I try to implement it like this

```
        double x;
        double y;


        x = (earth.Location.X - sun.Location.X) * Math.Cos(1);
        y = (earth.Location.Y - sun.Location.Y+30) * Math.Sin(1);

        earth.Location = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(x), Convert.ToInt32(y));
```

but is not really working,it's dissapearing from form, can someone help me ?

**P.S: i use a timer for that code**

Comment: Can you explain what is not working?

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? please be more specific.

Comment: it's dissapearing from form, i think is because i calucalte wrong **R1** and **R2**

Comment: are you using some sort of update function or timer to recalculate the earth location every so often? you should be if you want to see it move.

Comment: What was the expected values for R1 and R2, and what did you get instead?

Comment: that's the problem, i don't know how to get that value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to calculate the new position based on the old position. Instead, use the sun's position (fixed, I assume), the distance of earth from the sun, and the angle. Change the angle when you want to move the earth.

You need some setup like this:

```
// angle
double alpha = 0;   // radians, so from zero to 2*PI is a circle.

// distance from the sun
double r1 = 200; // or whatever you decide
double r2 = 100;
```

How to calculate Earth's position given the value of `alpha`:

```
x = sun.Location.X + (r1 * Math.Cos(alpha));
y = sun.Location.Y + (r2 * Math.Sin(alpha));
```

Next, you probably want to look at making `alpha` change value every few milliseconds so that Earth will move.